# Iterating with csv.DictReader

Tags: python, csv

I want to use csv.DictReader to read one column and depending on the value below, I would like to print the difference between the corresponding values in a different column: value below - the value above.

I wrote this script:

```
import csv

next=None
last = None
test_file = 'data.tsv'
csv_file = csv.DictReader(open(test_file, 'rU'), delimiter='\t')
for row in csv_file:
    if row['GT'] == "0/1":
        genotype = row['GT']
        if next is not None:
            if next == "0/1":
                position = int(row['pos'])
                if last is not None:
                    print  (position - last)
                last = position
        next = genotype
```

when I run it on data.tsv (see below) it does what it suppose to do, which is to print 80. Under the column GT, 0/1 occurs after 0/1 one time, and 832398-832318 = 80

```
pos GT
815069  0/0
825069  0/1
825410  ./.
830181  1/1
832318  0/1
832398  0/1
832756  0/0
```

However, when I set

if next == "0/0": (--> if first GT=0/1 and next GT=0/0, print the difference bewteen 
the corresponding values in the pos column, which is 832756-832398 = 358)

it prints nothing! Also when changing

if next == "./."

it does nothing

```
import csv

next=None
last = None
test_file = 'data.tsv'
csv_file = csv.DictReader(open(test_file, 'rU'), delimiter='\t')
for row in csv_file:
    if row['GT'] == "0/1":
        genotype = row['GT']
        if next is not None:
            **if next == "0/0":**
                position = int(row['pos'])
                if last is not None:
                    print  (position - last)
                last = position
        next = genotype
```

Any ideas why this might be?
Thankful for any help! Let me know if I should clarify the description of the problem (Python beginner)

Regards
Joanna

Answer (score 1):

The variable `next` in your first script is confusing, actually it is not the next, but the current GT. The script works only by chance, because both GTs are equal (so the order doesn't matter).

As you iterate your file row by row it is hardly possible to look ahead, instead you could look back and compare the current GT with the last GT like this:

```
import csv

last_gt = None
last_pos = None
test_file = 'data.tsv'
csv_file = csv.DictReader(open(test_file, 'rU'), delimiter='\t')
    for row in csv_file:
        curr_gt = row['GT']
        curr_pos = int(row['pos'])
        if (curr_gt == "0/0") and (last_gt == "0/1"): # EDIT: 'and' instead of '&'
            print(curr_pos - last_pos)
        last_pos = curr_pos                           # EDIT: delete 'else' statement
        last_gt = curr_gt
```

Comment: I think this is mostly the right answer. I'm not sure about the `else` block, probably the `last_whatever` values should be updated unconditionally at the end of the loop. Also, you should use the `and` operator rather than `&` in the `if` condition. The latter does a bitwise-and, which happens to work out fine in this situation, since both arguments are `bool`s, but it may not work correctly other contexts. For example, the expression `1 and 2` is `2` (which is truthy), but `1 & 2` is `0` (falsy).

Comment: Thank you @Blckknght for your explanatory comment. I think it's a good point, thus I'll edit my answer.